# Magento Error on product overview. How to find custom image problem

Tags: magento-1.9, image, product-images

can somebody help me? After googling I still don't know what to do, gettin following error:

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:25:"Image file was not found.";i:1;s:3454:"#0 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(166): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/c/a/carefully_...')
#1 /html/app/design/frontend/chicall/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml(105): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'second_image')
#2 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/app/desig...')
#3 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/chical...')
#4 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#8 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(90): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#9 /html/app/design/frontend/chicall/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(55): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#10 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/app/desig...')
#11 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/chical...')
#12 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#18 /html/app/design/frontend/chicall/default/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(49): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#19 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/html/app/desig...')
#20 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/chical...')
#21 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/CategoryController.php(161): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#27 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}";s:3:"url";s:59:"/blockname/site.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I think this is the code which causes it:

```
<?php if(($_product->getSecondImage() != null) && ($_product->getSecondImage() != 'no_selection')): ?>
                        <img class="second_image" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'second_image')->resize(240, 184); ?>" width="240" height="184" title="" alt="" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess there maybe two possible causes;
1) Check that the file actually exists at path supplied.
2) Check file permission of the file if it does.

This may only be a symptom of another problem though.